# How to get a string after a specific string?

Tags: python, parsing

How to get a string after a specific string?

As is

```py
a = ['$jas00051157$V0.20.30', '02-07-2021$debug.20210712_2327.24S_2481664$40$509b3bb3$jas1A8B7F7', '4889718:L]', '71001', '319', '187', '2', '2', '1', '4/49', '10/154', '16/106', '17/134', '18/244', '19/135', '20/139', '21/82', '22/344', '23/65', '26/190', '28/201', '29/224', '30/404', '31/223', '32/228', '33/201', 'L0', '199/208/204', 'L1', '211/216/213', '216/217/216', 'L2']
```

To be (I want to get after '71001' at python):

```py
['319', '187', '2', '2', '1', '4/49', '10/154', '16/106', '17/134', '18/244', '19/135', '20/139', '21/82', '22/344', '23/65', '26/190', '28/201', '29/224', '30/404', '31/223', '32/228', '33/201', 'L0', '199/208/204', 'L1', '211/216/213', '216/217/216', 'L2']
```

Answer (score 1):

In python there is the method `index` of `array` objects that can find the index of an element in the array.

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
i = my_list.index("b")
print(i)
# console: 1
```

With that you can use a slicer to get the end of the list starting by the index of the element you are tracking.

```py
my_list = ['$jas00051157$V0.20.30', '02-07-2021$debug.20210712_2327.24S_2481664$40$509b3bb3$jas1A8B7F7', '4889718:L]', '71001', '319', '187', '2', '2', '1', '4/49', '10/154', '16/106', '17/134', '18/244', '19/135', '20/139', '21/82', '22/344', '23/65', '26/190', '28/201', '29/224', '30/404', '31/223', '32/228', '33/201', 'L0', '199/208/204', 'L1', '211/216/213', '216/217/216', 'L2']

index = my_list.index("71001")

result = my_list[index+1:]
```